# Does Enumeration only work in legacy collection framework classes?

Tags: java, collections, stack, enumeration

Can anyone give confirmation that `Enumeration` only works with legacy collection framework classes?

I tried to retrieve elements of `Vector` and `Stack` using `Enumeration`, it works.

```
Stack<Integer> stack=new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.add(5);
    stack.add(9);
    System.out.println(stack);
    Enumeration<Integer> enumeration=stack.elements();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        Integer integer = (Integer) enumeration.nextElement();
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
```

but when I try this on `Set`, it does not work. So I am in confused about whether `Enumeration` only works for legacy collection frameworks classes or if `Enumeration` works with any class.

Comment: Show us the code that fails.

Comment: what do you mean by `It is not working`

Comment: "NOTE: The functionality of this interface is duplicated by the Iterator interface. In addition, Iterator adds an optional remove operation, and has shorter method names. New implementations should consider using Iterator in preference to Enumeration." ... Reading docs is fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumeartion not only work on legacy collection framework classes but also other collection framework classes.
while working with Stack or Vector,we can directly enumerate like this

```
Stack<Integer> stack=new Stack<Integer>();
        stack.add(5);
        stack.add(9);
        System.out.println(stack);
        Enumeration<Integer> enumeration=stack.elements();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
        Vector<Integer> vector=new Vector<Integer>();
        vector.add(5);
        vector.add(9);
        System.out.println(vector);
        Enumeration<Integer> enumeration2=vector.elements();
        while (enumeration2.hasMoreElements()) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) enumeration2.nextElement();
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
```

but when we are working with collection framework classes like HashSet,ArrayList etc we can enumerate by passing the object of the collection as argument to the Vector or Stack constructor.see the below code

```
Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>();
        set.add(6);
        set.add(7);
        System.out.println(set);
        Enumeration<Integer> enumeration3=new Vector(set).elements();
        while (enumeration3.hasMoreElements()) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) enumeration3.nextElement();
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
        List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(12);
        list.add(23);
        System.out.println(list);
        Enumeration<Integer> enumeration4=new Vector(list).elements();
        while (enumeration4.hasMoreElements()) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) enumeration4.nextElement();
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
```

Comment: **This has nothing to do with an `Enumeration` on `Set`.** It doesn't matter how you get the elements into the `Vector`, but that's what this is, an `Enumeration` on a `Vector` object.

Answer (score 2):

More recent Java collections have their own iterators that do a similar job. You also have things like the foreach loop to make things easier.

Comment: @rajeev ask a clearer question then...

Answer (score 1):

> when I try this in set then It is not working

Assuming you mean [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), that interface does not have a method that returns an `Enumeration` object, so it is no surprise that it will not work.

I'm also going to assume that since you are talking about legacy software, you *do* know about [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

---

<sub>Making a lot of assumptions here.</sub>

Comment: What can I correct/improve?